# Good approach for adding Multiple Filters to one Image

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement Photo Editor app.Everything is working fine but now when I'm trying to add more than one filter to image.It's not working as expected.
Basically what I did was I selected sepia effect and then sharpen the image and then put blur effect with very less radius.But if I first sharpen and then blur shapren. effect automatically gets removed.I'm unable to handle this situation

```
Below is my code:
 

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Photo Editor
//
//  
//

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var viewModels = [FilterViewModel]()
    private var currentOriginalImage:UIImage?
    private var currentFilteredImage:UIImage?
    private var selectedFilterIndex:Int = -1
   


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        setupViewModels()

    }



private func setupViewModels() {
        
        guard let demoImage = UIImage(named: "demo") else {
            return
        }
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Sepia),
                                          filterType: .Sepia))
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Chrome),
                                          filterType: .Chrome))
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Fade),
                                          filterType: .Fade))
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Mono),
                                          filterType: .Mono))
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Tonal),
                                          filterType: .Tonal))
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Transfer),
                                          filterType: .Transfer))
        viewModels.append(FilterViewModel(image: demoImage.addFilter(filter: .Noir),
                                          filterType: .Noir))
        
    }
```

// Setting filter to the image

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            guard let image = currentOriginalImage else {
                return
            }
            
            if selectedFilterIndex != indexPath.row {
                let viewModel = viewModels[indexPath.row]
                selectedFilterIndex = indexPath.row
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    let filteredImage = image.addFilter(filter: viewModel.filterType)
                    self?.currentFilteredImage = filteredImage
                    self?.imageView.image = filteredImage
                    self?.addOnFiltersView.blurSlider.value = 0
                    self?.addOnFiltersView.sharpenSlider.value = 0
                }
            }
            
            
        }

extension ViewController:AddOnFiltersViewDelegate{
    
    func addOnFiltersViewBlurEffect(_ addOnView: AddOnFiltersView,radius value: Float) {

        guard let image = currentFilteredImage else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            let filteredImage = image.addBlur(radius: value)
            self?.imageView.image = filteredImage
        }
    }
    
    func addOnFiltersViewSharpness(_ addOnView: AddOnFiltersView, sharpness value: Float) {
        guard let image = currentFilteredImage else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            let filteredImage = image.adjustSharpness(sharpness: value)
            self?.imageView.image = filteredImage
        }
        
    }
}

// Extension for creating filter

       extension UIImage {
    
    static let ciContext = CIContext()
    
    func addFilter(filter: FilterType) -> UIImage {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: filter.rawValue)
        
        let ciInput = CIImage(image: self)
        filter?.setValue(ciInput,
                         forKey: "inputImage")
        
        if let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage {
            if let cgImage = UIImage.ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput,
                                                             from: (ciOutput.extent)){
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
        
        return self
    }
    
    func addBlur(radius value:Float) -> UIImage {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBoxBlur")
        
        let ciInput = CIImage(image: self)
        
        filter?.setValue(ciInput,
                         forKey: "inputImage")
        filter?.setValue(value,
                         forKey: "inputRadius")
        
        if let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage, let ciInput = ciInput  {
            
            if let cgImage = UIImage.ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput,
                                                             from: (ciInput.extent)){
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
        
        return self
    }
    
    func adjustSharpness(sharpness value:Float) -> UIImage {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISharpenLuminance")
        
        let ciInput = CIImage(image: self)
        
        filter?.setValue(ciInput,
                         forKey: "inputImage")
        filter?.setValue(value,
                         forKey: "inputSharpness")
        
        if let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage, let ciInput = ciInput  {
            
            if let cgImage = UIImage.ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput,
                                                             from: (ciInput.extent)){
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
        
        return self
    }
    
}
```

Comment: A tip: you have a LOT of code there, doing a LOT of different things. Start with a single task... use a specific image (not "pick one from library")... do ONLY the one thing you're asking about: Sepia / Sharpen / Blur. That way we can grab those few lines of code and give it a test to help you figure it out.

Comment: @DonMag yeah sure let me refactor the code

Comment: @DonMag check now

Comment: Here's a quick example: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/fb26a3b5646cbc6746337adea2dd2d30 ... it loads a "sampleImage", sets it to two identical imageViews, adds a couple "info" labels... each Tap anywhere processes the next step. Top one goes "Sepia / Sharpen / Blur" bottom one goes "Sepia / Blur / Sharpen" ... 4th tap starts over. See if that represents what you're asking about... if so, explain what's not working as expected.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for writing this code.I want the exact thing but I tried your approach in my project but don't know issue is coming.Like when I add sepia then blur the image and try to sharpen image its get ruined. Can you please check my this repo https://github.com/shivamrishi98/Photo-Editor and switch to issues branch for checking if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Tough to say, because I don't know if the result from the sliders is correct or not (I don't know what you're expecting). First thought, though, is that your code appears to be applying the filters repeatedly - for example, if I slide the "Blur" slider back and forth, it doesn't *"blur and un-blur"* ... it just gets blurrier and blurrier. Is that your intent?

Comment: @DonMag yes thats the problem reptition of blur(or other effects)is the problem i think I’m making the filtered image to get filter again instead of original image